# How to Consume Secured Web Api from C# MVC and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

How to Consume Secured Web Api from other application C# MVC and AngularJS .

```
[Authorize(Users = "Steve,Mike")]
public class EmployeeController : ApiController
{
    MyDB db = new MyDB();

    public IEnumerable<EmployeeViewModel> GetAllEmployee()
    {
            return db.Employee.Select(item => new EmployeeViewModel { EmpID = item.EmpID, Name = item.Name, Region = item.Region }).ToList();
    }
}
```

The following code I can get without Secure WebApi from AngularJS

```
var ft = searchText.toLowerCase();
                $http.get('/api/Employee/GetAllEmployee').success(function (largeLoad) {
                    data = largeLoad.filter(function (item) {
                        return JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().indexOf(ft) != -1;
                    });
                    $scope.setPagingData(data, page, pageSize);
                });
```

Your help is highly appreciated...

Comment: What type of authentication are you using in your MVC project?

Comment: Assuming the client is authenticated and authorized at the moment you make the request, have you tried setting the `withCredentials` property on the `$http.config` object? That would look something like `$http({ withCredentials: true }).get('/api/Employee/GetAllEmployee')` and so on.

Comment: We really need to see how authentication is handled in the API before we can help.

Answer (score -3):

what kind of Secured Web Api do you want to consume?
you may think about oAuth

Comment: Please use this as a comment on the question. It is not an answer

Comment: Not to mention this doesn't make sense in the context of ASP.NET

Comment: @devqon it is impossible at the moment... it is not possible add a comment if the reputation is less than 50.. thank you

Comment: @CallumLinington why doesn't make sense ? it can use oAuth with AngularJs and web api...